# How can I use the imported class FragmentManager inside an OnClickListener class called inside my existing class?

Tags: java, android, oop

Inside the loop of a part of my application, I assigned an onclick listener to my LinearLayout `conteach` but I can't use the class `FragmentManager` that's why I can't perform transactions on my fragments. I know that the problem is because I'm inside the `OnClickListener` class, and there is no existing `FragmentManager`, how can I use the imported class `FragmentManager` inside an `onClickListener` class?

```
conteach.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            SpecificArticleFragment spcf = new SpecificArticleFragment();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putString("art_id", v.getTag().toString());
                            spcf.setArguments(args);
                            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        }
                     });
```

This is the code for my whole class.

```
package com.example.navigationdrawerexample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Connector extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    private Context context;
    private TextView headline;
    private int collegeactive;
    private String flag;
    private TextView senderofheadline;
    private TextView shortdescofheadline;
    private LinearLayout listofitems;

    public Connector(Context context,int college, String flag,TextView headline, TextView shortdesc, TextView sender,LinearLayout ll){
        this.context = context;
        this.headline = headline;
        this.collegeactive = college;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.senderofheadline = sender;
        this.shortdescofheadline = shortdesc;
        this.listofitems = ll;
    }


    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this.context);

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            String link = "";
            if (flag ==  "headline"){
                link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printHeadline&coll_id="+collegeactive;
            } else if (flag == "list"){
                link = "http://rtu-astronet.com/emag/functions.php?action=printArticlePerCollege&collegeid="+collegeactive+"&acadornot=1";
            }
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                //break;
            }

            in.close();
            return sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e){
             return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        result = "{ \n \"Data\": \n " + result + " \n }";

        if (flag == "headline"){
            try{
                JSONObject jsonRootObj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObj.optJSONArray("Data");
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                this.headline.setText(jsonObject.optString("title").toString());
                this.shortdescofheadline.setText(jsonObject.optString("shortdesc").toString());
                this.senderofheadline.setText(jsonObject.optString("penname").toString());
            } catch(JSONException e){
                this.headline.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
            }

        } else if (flag == "list"){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonRootObj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObj.optJSONArray("Data");

                for (int p = 0; p < jsonArray.length(); p++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(p);
                    LinearLayout conteach = new LinearLayout(this.context);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    conteach.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    conteach.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    TextView art_title = new TextView(this.context);
                    art_title.setText(jsonObject.optString("title").toString());
                    art_title.setTextSize(20);
                    art_title.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(350,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    TextView art_shortdesc = new TextView(this.context);
                    art_shortdesc.setText(jsonObject.optString("shortdesc").toString());
                    art_shortdesc.setTextSize(14);
                    art_shortdesc.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
                    art_shortdesc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(350,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    TextView art_sender = new TextView(this.context);
                    art_sender.setText("Written by: " + jsonObject.optString("sender").toString());
                    art_sender.setTextSize(14);
                    art_sender.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(350,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    art_sender.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 15);

                    conteach.setTag(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
                    conteach.setClickable(true);
                    conteach.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            /* 
                             * CollegeBulletinListFragment cblf = new CollegeBulletinListFragment();
                                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                args.putString("passingWord", passingword);
                                cblf.setArguments(args);
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, cblf).commit();
                             */

                            SpecificArticleFragment spcf = new SpecificArticleFragment();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putString("art_id", v.getTag().toString());
                            spcf.setArguments(args);
                            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 

                        }
                     });
                    conteach.addView(art_title);
                    conteach.addView(art_shortdesc);
                    conteach.addView(art_sender);

                    this.listofitems.addView(conteach);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e){

            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: is this an Activity class ? Please post more code.

Comment: A class that extends an <AsyncTask>, anyway, the Fragment class that uses this class has a constructor and assign a context that contains the class of the fragment class

Comment: Or just assume that it's an activity class.

Comment: Please post your activity's code

Comment: I already did, see answers.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I use the imported class FragmentManager inside an
>   onClickListener class?

We can get `FragmentManager` from Activity Context currently `getFragmentManager` method calling inside `onClick` method is causing issue because this method is not available inside `OnClickListener`.

If Button is inside `Fragment` then use `getActivity()` for getting `Activity` Context :

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
```

**OR**

If Button is inside class which is extending `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` then :

```
 FragmentManager fm = ActivityClassName.this.getFragmentManager();
```

**NOTE:** To call `getFragmentManager` method you need `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` Context.

Comment: How if my class extends <AsynchTask> the code is located at the postexecute() method?

Comment: @JohnRannielSinel: in `onPostExecute` use  `FragmentManager fm =((Activity)context) .getFragmentManager(); `

Comment: the context variable is a fragment class, should I use, ((Fragment)context)?

Comment: Inside the onclicklistener class, the context is not availble, is there a way to get it?

Comment: @JohnRannielSinel no please use Activity instead of Fragment

Comment: Eventhough the context variable comes from the fragment class? I can still Activity?

Comment: @JohnRannielSinel: Considering passing `getActivity` from Fragment ? then use `FragmentManager fm =((Activity)context) .getFragmentManager();`

Comment: Okay, but how can I access the context? I have tried ((Activity)Connector.this.context).getFragmentManager, but it's not working :(

Comment: @JohnRannielSinel: `but it's not working` means? showing any error?

Comment: First error, it requires me to import activity so I did.

Comment: Second error, it requires me to change the `FragmentManager` fm to Acitivy

Comment: I don't know if it is correct but it returns no error `FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) Connector.this.context).getFragmentManager();`

Comment: Help, it returns an error that It cannot be cast to Activity class.

Comment: @JohnRannielSinel: Please share log

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

set an interface

```
public interface TestListener {
    void layoutClick();
}
```

in your connector class

```
private TestListener mListener;
```

and a set method

```
public void setListener(TestListener listener) {
      mListener =  listener;
}
```

in your activity, when you create Connector, you can set listener

```
your connector.setListener(new TestListener() {
            @Override
            public void layoutClick() {
                //it's in your activity. so you can use
                //FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            }
});
```

and last in your Connector class, inside onClick

```
if (mListener != null) {
    mListener.layoutClick();
}
```

Hope this help!!!

Comment: I'm just wondering, what should I code inside the interface? Can you give me at least a hint?

Comment: edited. you can call getFragmentManager(); inside. and do what you want to do next.